# How can mercury be removed from the body "naturally"?

Tags: blood

Is it possible to remove mercury from the (live) human body without undergoing [chelation therapy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chelation_therapy)? Does the body remove it naturally?

> He switched to salmon and his mercury levels fell by half

-- [article on Lee Hood](http://www.geekwire.com/2015/genomics-pioneer-lee-hood-new-startup-could-be-the-google-or-microsoft-of-scientific-wellness/)

The first ~50 Google search results have been spectacularly unhelpful, pointing to "alternative" medicine pages like Mercola. Wikipedia didn't have anything on the topic (or I was unable to find it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently the body does remove mercury naturally:

> Sixty days after the amalgam removal, the Hg levels in blood, plasma, and urine had declined to approximately 60% of the pre-removal levels. [...] After removal, there was a considerable decline in the Hg levels of blood, plasma, and urine, which slowly approached those of subjects without any history of amalgam fillings.

-- Sandborgh-Englund G1, Elinder CG, Langworth S, Schütz A, Ekstrand J. - *[Mercury in biological fluids after amalgam removal](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/9539465)* - J Dent Res. 1998 Apr;77(4):615-24.